# Workspace cleanup plugin disabled, but Workspace clean-up.log still being created

Tags: jenkins, workspace

Workspace cleanup plugin 0.39 installed.

The jobs are not configured to delete the workspace before or after the build.

The workspace for a specific job was recently deleted on 9 nodes.  This was logged in /jenkinsserver/logs/tasks/Workspace clean-up.log.

I restarted jenkins with -Dhudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.disabled=true

Now the Workspace cleanup is not checked as Enabled under jenkins Plugin Manager.

Yet this morning there is another Workspace clean-up log:

-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins sfcb    2839 Apr 22 01:27 'Workspace clean-up.log'

and other workspaces are being deleted.

Why is this running and how do I control it?